# Vector<double> vs. Double.Vector error in F# when using BfgsSolver

Tags: f#, mathematical-optimization, math.net

I'm trying to use the BfgsSolve method from MathNet.Numerics for F# on a simple test case I wrote, but I'm running into a type mismatching issue.

Here's my code:

```
#r "nuget: MathNet.Numerics, 5.0.0-alpha08"
#r "nuget: MathNet.Numerics.FSharp, 5.0.0-alpha08"
open MathNet.Numerics.Optimization 
open MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra


let vecGuess = vector [double 1.0]

let sineFuncTest (x : Vector<float>) = 
    let xval = x.[0]
    System.Math.Sin (xval ** 2.0  - 1.0 )

let sinegrad (x : Vector<float>) = 
    let xval = x.[0]
    vector [2.0 * xval * (System.Math.Cos (xval ** 2.0 - 1.0))]

let result = BfgsSolver.Solve (vecGuess, sineFuncTest ,sinegrad)
```

However the BfgsSolve function won't accept my `vecGuess` variable. The error I get is: `error FS0001: The type 'Vector<double>' is not compatible with the type 'Double.Vector'`.

What's the difference between the two? I've tried and failed to create a `Double.Vector` type.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will compile and run if you create your guess like this:

```ml
open MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double

let vecGuess = DenseVector [|1.0|]
```

I don't know if the answer is correct, though. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45563696/converting-an-f-function-with-multiple-parameters-to-a-func-type-mathnet-nume) for a similar example.

Comment: Thanks. That example compiles, though for some reason the function `BfgsSolver.Solve` produces the wrong answer. I was able to get a correct answer by following [these csharp examples](https://www.csharpcodi.com/csharp-examples/MathNet.Numerics.Optimization.BfgsMinimizer.FindMinimum(MathNet.Numerics.Optimization.IObjectiveFunction,%20MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Vector)/) and converting to FSharp. I'm not sure what the `Solve` function is supposed to do or if I'm using it wrong. The documentation for this package is awful, lol.